# Google Home Cast - Different Network

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-assistant

Is it possible to send a broadcast command to a Google mini that is on a different network? Basically, I can access Google Home mini from my laptop, but the mini can't access my laptop because I have a router in the middle - which means my laptop can reach the mini's API, but I can't discovery the device, as the mini can't send packages back to my laptop.

Is there any local api that can be called? In other words, my laptop can initiate the call and ask google mini to play the audio - like a manual discovery, as the mini's IP is fixed.

Or is there a Google Cloud API capable of playing the audio?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

The sample below contains the parameter called --known-host, which connects to a device that is available. As I mentioned, my device is reachable from my laptop, but cannot ping my laptop from outside.

https://github.com/home-assistant-libs/pychromecast/blob/master/examples/bbcsounds_example.py